# Develop a custom Backdrop App

Tags: chromecast

Is it possible to develop a custom Backdrop App for Google Chromecast instead of using Google's Backdrop feature? It doesn't support some features and I have some ideas, so want to see if that is possible. Documentation didn't provide me that information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that area is not open to developers to change; users can decide on the source of content there (images from various sources, news, etc) but beyond that, there is no access to backdrop for developers.

Comment: thanks..such a shame.. using google+ or google photos is the worst.. they r a blot on social softwares..except free space